# vim :make without external window

Tags: vim, makefile

in vim, when I use

```
:make
```

the output of make is displayed in a "external" window, I don't like this and I use this map

```
 nnoremap <leader>m :w <bar> make<CR><CR><CR>:copen<CR>
```

but, in some case the output of make is

```
 make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

how I can add a autoclose to copen  when the copen have `make: Nothing to be done for all.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the contents of the quickfix list via `getqflist()`. Then, I would only conditionally open the quickfix window if the first line does not match the text you don't want to see:

```
nnoremap <leader>m :w <bar> make<CR><CR><CR>
\:if get(get(getqflist(), 0, {}), 'text', '') !~# 'Nothing to be done' <Bar> 
\  copen <Bar>
\endif<CR>
```

The access via `get()` avoids errors when the list is empty.

You could also always open the list, and then use `:cclose` in the conditional, if that better fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

i have a vim script that helps me a lot:

- first it saves the current edit window (if possible, won't work if read only)
- then it runs make and redirects errors (stderr) to temp file (stdout is ignored)
- if build failed then open quick fix windows and fill it with error messages.
- delete temporary file

```
command! -nargs=* Build call s:RunBuild()

function! s:RunBuild()
    let tmpfile = tempname()

    "build and surpresses build status messages to stdout
    "(stdout message are not very informative and may be very very long)
    "Error messages are redirected to temporary file.
    let buildcmd = "make -j 2> " . tmpfile . " >/dev/null"

    let fname = expand("%")
    if fname != ""
        " save current buffer if possible (your bad if file is read only)
        write
    endif

    " --- run build command --- 
    echo "Running make ... "
    let cmd_output = system(buildcmd)

    "if getfsize(tmpfile) == 0
    if v:shell_error == 0
      cclose
      execute "silent! cfile " . tmpfile
      echo "Build succeded"
    else

      let old_efm = &efm
      set efm=%f:%l:%m
      execute "silent! cfile " . tmpfile
      let &efm = old_efm

      botright copen
    endif

    call delete(tmpfile)
endfunction
```

Then i map the F5 key to do the build in each vim mode

```
"F5 - run make (in normal mode)
:nnoremap  :Build

"F5 - run make (in visual mode)
:vnoremap  :Build

"F5 - run make (in insert mode)
:inoremap  :Build
```